# Assistance understanding short watercolor shader code?

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I am new to shaders and trying to understand how some of them work. I found one which looks very cool and is less than 20 lines, but I cannot figure out what's actually going on with all the single-letter variable names.

Would somebody be able to explain how this works?

[Here](http://glslsandbox.com/e#70301.0) you can see the output of the shader with code.

And here is the code:

```
precision highp float;
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution;
varying vec2 surfacePosition;

void main() {
    vec2 u = (1.5 - 4.0) * surfacePosition;
    vec3 ht = smoothstep(0.0, 2.0, 12.0 - dot(u, u)) * vec3(u * 0.02, -1.0);
    vec3 n = 100.0 * normalize(ht - vec3(0.0, -0.5 * fract(0.015), 0.65));
    vec3 p = n;
    for (float i = 0.0; i <= 10.0; i++) {
        p = 10.0 * n + vec3(cos(0.255 * time - i - p.x) + cos(0.255 * time + i - p.y), sin(i - p.y) + cos(i + p.x), 9);
        p.xy = cos(i) * p.xy + sin(i) * vec2(p.y, -p.x);
    }
    float tx = 5.0 * sqrt(dot(vec3(2, 0.2, 4), -p));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(pow(sin(vec3(9, 0.4, 1.1) - tx) * 0.55 + 0.25, vec3(0.5)), 2.5);
```

Comment: *"I cannot figure out what's actually going on with all the single-letter variable names."* - You are looking for a tutorial. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: No, just looking to understand the general logic

Comment: I don't think a question of the kind "I don't know what this code does" meets the guidelines.

Comment: Have you considered trying to modify the code to see how it works for yourself? You could for example comment out the `gl_FragColor =` line and instead write `gl_FragColor = vec4(u, 1.0, 1.0)` as a starting point to see what the `u =` line does, and then do the same for subsequent variables.